# c# Asp.net mvc identity, .AspNet.ApplicationCookie invalid after ten minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I am using Asp.net identity membership. This is Startup.Auth.cs code :

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),  
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))

            }
        });
```

As you can see i've set 45 minutes and it generates Asp.Net.ApplicationCookie, but  Users are  logging out about in ten minutes if they are inactive(not send http request). Asp.Net.ApplicationCookie still exists but it's invalid(after ten minutes) .  Why it's invalid after ten minutes does not supposed to be after 45 minutes?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET SessonState?

Comment: It's a defualt mvc 5 project, identity version 2.2.1

Comment: In the whole day i couldn't find any solutin  :/

Comment: You should not open up 2 of the exact same questions. If you have information to add then add it to the already open question. By creating an edit in your question it gets flagged and moved back to the top of the question queue.

Comment: Like I said: edit your question to provide additional details. What have you tried so far, browsers, etc. When you edit your question it will pop back up to the top of the list for everyone on SO so its becomes visible again.

Comment: I didn't know that ok

Comment: But this one stay as exception maybe someone